# Using Android UIAutomator in Python or Ruby

Tags: android, python, ruby, automation, ui-automation

I am trying to automate android apps using python (or possibly ruby), by linking into the provided UIAutomator in the android SDK.

Right now I am trying to use a Python tool [here](https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator), but I am having issues connecting (getting `TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`.

Code snipped of what i am trying to do with the Python tool:

```
    def print_info():
        print('Getting info...')
        d = ui.Device('SERIAL_NUMBER', adb_server_host='192.168.1.20', adb_server_port='5037')
        print(d.info)
```

Is there something wrong with how I am trying to send commands? Alternatively, is there a better ruby/python tool for testing android devices?

**Update** I am now using the Appium library Ruby gem to test. Got applications to launch, however things like tapping the screen result in this error

```
assert_ok': A session is either terminated or not started
(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError)`
```

This is the code

```
desired_caps = {
  caps:       {
    appiumVersion:    '1.6.5',
    platformName:     'Android',
    platformVersion:  '4.4',
    browserName:      '',
    deviceName:       'DEVICE_SERIAL',
    app:              'APK',
    appActivity:      'mainactivity',
    appWaitDuration:  '60000', # wait a minute (set to 20000 by default)
    clearSystemFiles: 'true'
  },
  appium_lib: {
    sauce_username:    nil,
    sauce_access_key:  nil
  }
}

$driver = Appium::Driver.new(desired_caps)
$driver.start_driver
sleep(60) # wait a minute for app to fully load, before tring to tap anything
touch_action = Appium::TouchAction.new
touch_action.press(x: 243, y: 288).wait(5).release.perform
touch_action.press(x: 311, y: 165).wait(5).release.perform
```

Comment: one thing which I observed is the app field.. it should have a full path to the apk file which is under test....

Answer (score 0):

There is an one good mobile test automation tool available - Appium.
Currently I have been using ruby,appium,cucumber,selenium webdriver for android automation. I am suggesting that you will try to use Appium tool for mobile automation. below is important link,

http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/09/appium-tutorials.html
https://community.perfectomobile.com/posts/1103155-ruby-example-for-appium-android
http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/android.html?ruby#troubleshooting

```
following is the example to start  
require 'appium_lib'  
desired_caps = {  
     caps:       {   appiumVersion:    '1.6.0',  
      platformName:     'Android',  
      platformVersion:  '4.4.2',    
      browserName:       '',  
     deviceName:       'Samsung Galaxy S4 Emulator',  
     app:              'D:\Workspace\android-sample-app.apk',         
    name:             'Ruby Appium Sauce example'   
  }       }   
driver = Appium::Driver.new(desired_caps)  
puts driver  
begin  
  driver.start_driver  
  rescue Exception => e   
  puts e     
end
driver.first_textfield.send_key 10 
driver.last_textfield.send_key 20  
driver.first_button.click  
driver.driver_quit   
download "android-sample-app.apk" and put in any path and also set this path 
in desired_caps.
```

Thanks,
Kapil Chothe

Comment: I am currently trying to use Appium with Ruby, but am unable to get a simple test to work properly. Any good examples on how to start with it?

Comment: its extremely simple, there might be some errors in your appium setup or ruby setup... Please mention in details what have you done and I can help debug the framework and help you set it up...     
1) Install appium-doctor and run "appium-doctor --android" and paste the output here .  
2) ruby --version .  
3) and error log when you execute your appium test..

Comment: I updated the above post to show what I am trying to do in Appium.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it for an emulator

```
app_path = File.absolute_path('automateme.apk', 'data')
caps = {
  :platformName => "android",
  :deviceName => "android",
  :app => app_path,
  :noReset => 'true',
  :newCommandTimeout => "30"
}

@driver = Appium::Driver.new(:caps => caps).start_driver
```

try this and let me know if it helps... :)

Comment: I was able to get the app to start like above, however now when I run it I get: "in `assert_ok': An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: You must include a platformName capability (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)". Before, when I was able to launch the app, I was having issues pressing/tapping at a given location

Comment: I also exact same thing in Python, go the same "You must include a platformName error". It is something with Selenium.

Comment: Nope it is not anything to do with Selenium... Lets figure this out, can you share the following details, ruby version, output of "appium-doctor --android", have you give full apk path for your app??  What emulator are you using, is the emulator running when you trigger this script... ?

Comment: I got it working now, I was nesting extra in desired caps, which caused the issue. It is also technically tapping the device at the specified location, but too early (takes time for the app to load), it is possible to wait before the commands are actually performed?

Comment: Also, is it possible to instead connect to an already running Appium server using the url (localhost:port/wd/hub), instead of using caps each time, and having to restart the server/app each time?